# Identify this 16 crossing knot

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

For this knot with DT code
-8 16 28 14 -2 6 -20 10 24 -32 -12 -30 18 -22 4 -26
I received an error message from Knot Finder:
"KnotFinder encountered an unknown error."

I also tried SnapPy (using the Plink Editor and sending the information to SnapPy). The command M.identify() yielded: [].

I suspect that the knot is 16n847920. Who can help to identify this knot and why does it produce the above results? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think SnapPy's identify method doesn't search through 16-crossing knots because there are too many of them, but if you set "M=Manifold('DT:[(-8,16,28,14,-2,6,-20,10,24,-32,-12,-30,18,-22,4,-26)]')" then "Manifold('16n847920').is_isometric_to(M)" should still return True.

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks. This check works. As a remark I would like to add that Knot Finder recognises the knot 16n847920 with other input and returns the minimal DT code 6 -10 28 30 -14 -4 18 -8 22 12 -26 16 -32 -20 2 -24 for it. The message "unknown error" only occurs for some diagram inputs.

Comment: @StevenSivek - Perhaps add that comment as a short answer which can then be accepted?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer, I think SnapPy's identify method doesn't search through 16-crossing knots because there are too many of them, but if you think you know which knot you have then SnapPy can still verify your guess:

```
In[1]: M=Manifold('DT:[(-8,16,28,14,-2,6,-20,10,24,-32,-12,-30,18,-22,4,-26)]')

In[2]: Manifold('16n847920').is_isometric_to(M)

Out[2]: True
```

Comment: Thanks. This is already helpful. There are two remaining topics:
1) Does anyone find an identification of the above knot when we do not already have a candidate for it? (Which other tools might be successful in this case?)
2) For somebody with a local installation of Knotscape: Does the same error message occur as in Knot Finder? (And can the cause of the error message be located in the code?)

Comment: For (1), you could just iterate through NonalternatingKnotExteriors() in SnapPy.  Volume computations are fast, so for every knot K whose volume was within 0.001 of M.volume(), I used M.is_isometric_to(K) to compare them.  It found 16n847920 in just over 45 minutes, which is fine for isolated examples but I'd also like to know if there's a faster way.

Answer (score 9):

I just tried [Knotscape](https://web.math.utk.edu/%7Emorwen/knotscape.html) on this knot and it immediately identified it as 16n847920.

Comment: Welcome to mathoverflow!

Comment: Hi Morwen!  Glad to "see" you here.